# How to replicate two rabbitmq server

Tags: rabbitmq

I have two server and this server have installed to rabbitmq.How to replicate these rabbitmq server? One of them is down when you want the other active.

-Server Name : Rabbit1 ,Node Name:rabbit@rabbit1
-Server Name : Rabbit2, Node Name:rabbit@rabbit2

Now,I use rabbit2 server.At the same time Publishers sends to message Rabbit1 Server but if Rabbit1 server shutdown,Publishers sends to message Rabbit2 server and then Consumers should continue reading Rabbit2 server.What should I do for it? Options :

-Two different servers using load balancer
-Two different servers using cluster but Rabbit2 server must join to Rabbit1 server cluster system.

Comment: How to replicate these rabbitmq server? your question is not clear, can you elaborate it. Are you looking for how to access the web UI?

Answer (score -1):

You want clustering and/or high availability queues. You can find the basic guides in the RabbitMQ documentation, here:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

and here:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html